# Kendo angular grid handle errors

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-angular-ui

I am trying to use Kendo ui angular grid (in cell editing), but I want to know if there is a way to handle error from server side that occurs when editing data?

Comment: To properly answer, there is some key information missing. Code snippet ? A bit more context ? There are multiple ways to make an edit from the Kendo Grid (inline editing, in-cell editing, etc.). Is your data part of a form ?